# get all disabled checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to be able to retrieve all checkboxes that are disabled and add a style/background to the containing TD table cell. I can select all checkboxes and change the background as follows:

```
$(':checkbox').closest("td").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
```

I just need to update this so that it applies to only disabled items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `:disabled` selector:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:disabled').closest("td") // .addClass('disabled');
```

Note that `:checkbox` selector has been deprecated, the alternative is attribute selector.

You can also use `has` method:

```
$('td').has('input[type=checkbox]:disabled').css('background-color', '#FF0000')
```

Comment: Got both of these to work. There was an issue with my code which stopped it from working.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I misunderstood `disabled`, I think you need:

`$(':checkbox:not(:checked)').closest("td").css('background-color', '#FF0000');`

If you can't do it inline, you can always iterate:

```
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
  var cb = $(this);
  if(cb.is(':disabled')) {
    cb.closest("td").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm not looking for checked/unchecked boxes. I need to only apply the rule to disabled checkboxes wether they be checked or not.

Comment: Oh, then surely `:checkbox:disabled` is the correct selector?

Comment: See my edit. Would still be interested if there's a one-line solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(':checkbox:disabled').closest("td").css('background-color', '#FF0000');
```